# Compile error CMAKE with CUDA on Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, cuda, visual-studio-2017

I am having a problem compiling a project with CUDA on VS2017 c++.

[image]

I can get rid of this error by just changing the line in
Properties->CUDA C/C++->Command Line-> Additional Options:

```
%(AdditionalOptions) -Zi /W3 /wd4005 /wd4003 /wd4996 /nologo -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0"
```

[image]

changed to

[image]

```
%(AdditionalOptions) -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Ob2"
```

After changing this option, the project compiles without any errors.

My Question is, how can I do it from CMAKE so that I don't have to change this property every time I regenerate the project?

Comment: You have not shown what the error actually is, nor the Cmake file which produces the error, and the images you have posted are completely unhelpful to the next person who tries searching because they can't be searched. please fix these things if you want help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .sln file is generated from cmake. You can use cmake-gui.exe to load the cmake cache file and query strings, then override that string in your CMakeLists.txt.

For your case, you would like to remove the annoying "/W3 /wd4005 /wd4003 /wd4996 /nologo " options. You can do like this:

[image: example usage of finding string in cmake cache]
Here, I open cmake-gui.exe, fillin the source folder and build folder of your project, and type "w3" in search box, and get "CMAKE_C_FLAGS". So you can override "CMAKE_C_FLAGS" in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "") # set it to empty

# you may also replace some options inside it, go and query cmake docs to see how to do that
```

Then, clean all the previous generated build files and re-cmake.